# Minecraft fullscreen is invisible

Tags: 14.04, minecraft, fullscreen

I have a system running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have played Minecraft on Windows for a few years, and decided to install it to Ubuntu so I wouldn't have to reboot to play it. On Ubuntu, however, when I try to go to fullscreen with <kbd>F11</kbd>, it becomes invisible, making me have to turn off fullscreen and exit the game, as it becomes stuck with the background that was behind it. There are many other questions here about it not working, but none seem to address my particular case.

**Edit:** I play on servers quite often, so I can't just use another game.

**Edit 2:** I run a 64-bit quad-core Intel i7-2600K CPU with 8GB of RAM, and use the default environment.

Comment: Are you using the default desktop environment (Unity) or something else? What are your specs?